# Book Recommendations : Computational Complexity Theory and Graph problems

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

I need recommendations for books which deal with classes of Algorithms(P, NP, NP-C etc). I'm interested in knowing new prooving techniques, proving why an algorithm is NP-C(I recently read about the Vertex cover problem and found it's proof mechanism really interesting, I'd like to learn about various Graph theory problems). I'd appreciate it if you could recommend a book which covers the topics I want, sorry If I'm misusing any terminology, I'm quite new to this field.

Comment: P, NP, etc. are classes of problems, not classes of algorithms.  Are you interested in methods for analyzing the running time of algorithms (e.g. this algorithm runs in polynomial time), or in methods for showing that a problem is in a class such as P or NP?

Comment: @Brian Borchers In methods showing the class of a problem, sorry about that.

Comment: 1. P, NP, and NP-Completeness: The Basics of Computational Complexity by
Oded Goldreich 2. Computational Complexity A Conceptual Perspective  by
Oded Goldreich

Comment: @W.R.P.S thanks for the recommendation. I'll try reading them.

Answer (score 0):

Skiena "Algorithm Design Manual" is a great book for learning techniques, and it also contains all most important algorithms. If you want more rigorous treatment of ideas, get Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein "Introduction to Algorithms".

Comment: The OP is looking for recommendations on Computational Complexity, not on the Analysis of Algorithms.